# Is there any other way for lookahead?

Tags: regex

I would like to split the input as shown below. This input contains a data type that has two parts. First part is the title, [XX] or [YY], and the other part is content (contents may contain \r\n\r\n or [XX] or [YY]). When the content finished, new data starts with \r\n\r\n[XX] OR \r\n\r\n[YY]:

```
[XX]\r\n
bla bla\r\n
bla bla\r\n
\r\n
[YY]\r\n
bla [XX] bla\r\n
bla bla\r\n
\r\n
[YY]\r\n
bla [YY] bla\r\n\r\n
bla bla\r\n
\r\n
```

I wrote two regex for catch and split this input, two of them are working but i think, they can be improved.

First: `\[(XX|YY)\]\r\n((?:(?!\r\n\r\n\[(XX|YY)\]).)*)`

Second (works good except the last data): `\[(XX|YY)\]\r\n(.*?)(?=\r\n\r\n\[(XX|YY)\])`

Both of them have ".*", so they use lots of backtrack, is there any what to do this with [^]?

Thanks...

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to use match instead of split. Is using split an unmovable requirement or would you also consider match-based approaches?

Comment: i can use match-based solutions also i am using this pattern in c# with regex.match...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both are fine and don't have any more backtracking than necessary. You could anchor the title part to the start of the line, but that shouldn't make much of a difference:

```
(?m)^\[(XX|YY)\]\r\n((?:(?!\r\n\r\n\[(?:XX|YY)\]).)*)
```

But perhaps your language already provides this functionality? It looks like you're trying to parse a Windows-style configuration (`.ini`) file. For example, Python has the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) module for that.

Comment: but i'm not parsing .ini or any known configration file. i want to use this pattern for parsing our custom log file...